# N-gram translations from Spanish to English

Tags: english, spanish, n-grams, resource-request

I have a large list of n-grams for spoken Spanish. I wish to establish for each n-grams whether or not it represents something idiomatic (phrasal verb, idiom etc.) or not.

For example, these are idiomatic:

```
"tomar el pelo” -> "pulling one's leg" (literarily "take the hair")
"darse prisa" -> "hurry up" (literarily "give hurry")
```

while these are not:

```
"bola roja" -> "red ball"
"el primero" -> "the first"
```

I would also like to know what the English translation(s) is for those n-grams which are idiomatic in nature.

I can program so perhaps a solution might involve me searching a Spanish-English dictionary in the form of a database file.

Comment: There won't be one that's too terribly useful. *contar con* could mean any of the following off the top of my head: count on, to count on, counting on, counted on, count with, to count with, counting with, counted with, count alongside, to count alongside, counting alongside, to count alongside....

Comment: @guifa Updated my question to make it clearer regarding what I'm after.